# Nested/Recursive string interpolation in R? string::str_interp

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, rmysql

I'm writing a function that creates a MySQL query based on a template and a named list of columns. However, one of the columns in the named list contains a function that returns sql code that should go into the query line. If I call `str_interp` on the whole thing, everything is converted except the function line, which remains as a function.

Below is a very simplified reproducible example. I know the function works to create the query, and the whole thing works if I then call:
`query <- stringr::str_interp(query)` or
`query <- stringr::str_interp(stringr::str_interp(DEFAULT_QUERY))` but that feels redundant and potentially dangerous in some other context? I'm wondering if there's a better way to recursively `str_interp` or just force it to evaluate afterwards. Any ideas?

Also, unsure if there's a better way to quote things in the `score_format_function` as I'm new to quasiquotation. Thanks!

```
DEFAULT_QUERY <- "SELECT ${paste(grplines, collapse=',\n  ')} FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.uid = t2.uid;"

features <- list(
    `Age`='t1.age',
    `Gender`='t2.gender',
    `Race`='t2.race',
    `Processed Score`='${score_format_function(score, 10, 100)}'
)

grplines <- paste0(features, ' as `', names(features), '`')
query <- string::str_interp(DEFAULT_QUERY)

score_format_function <- function(column, number, ...) {
  rlang::as_stringr(rlang::enexpr(column))
  rlang::enexpr(number)
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)
  paste0(column, '\\', number, ' - ', dots[[1]])
}
```

Comment: There are some typos in your function `rlang::rlang::`.  I get some errors with your code `rror in rlang::list2(...) : object 'arg2' not found`

Comment: Did you mean `query <- stringr::str_interp(DEFAULT_QUERY)` ? How do you call `score_format_function` function? Do you have an example?

Comment: Fixed the typos, apologies about that. arg1 and arg2 were just generics but I replaced them with numbers which is how they are used in practice.

Comment: I think my best bet is something like `while(stringr::str_detect(query, '\\${')) query <- stringr::str_interp(DEFAULT_QUERY)`